# Evaluate double integral of triangular region

Tags: integration

Evaluate $$ \int\int_D e^{y^2} dA  $$ where D is the triangular region with vertices (0,0), (0,1) and (2,1)

My attempts:

$$ \int^{2}_0 \int^{1}_\frac{x}{2} e^{y^2} dy dx $$
or
$$ \int^{0}_1\int^{2y}_2 e^{y^2} dx dy $$

but I couldn't evaluate the integral so I think I must've done something wrong when finding the region D.

Comment: So close on that second one! The left boundary is the $y$-axis--that is, the line $x=0$--so instead of $\int_2^{2y}$, you should have $\int_0^{2y}$ on your inner integral. That goof made your integral problematic to evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral $$\int_0^2\int_{x/2}^1 e^{y^2} dy dx$$ is hard to evaluate, so you need to get the $dx$ inside. The following will do:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2y} e^{y^2} dx dy.$$
Evaluation is simple:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^{2y} e^{y^2} dx dy &= \int_0^1 2y e^{y^2} dy \\
                                  &= \left[e^{y^2}\right]_0^1 \\
                                  &= e-1.
\end{align}

Comment: Right! It's 3 in the morning so I forget how to evaluate integrals. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is a tricky question. The is no elementary-function that is equal to the integral of e to the 'x-squared' power. That integral is very common in calculus books to show this phenomena. (I am not an english-speaking native, I went to a spanish-speaking college and I don't remember the english term)

You can get computed values using a numeric approach.

You could see some discussion about this in http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=103752